# Firebase Database: why do the key/ref in my queried datasnapshot refer to its parent?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I would like to delete an entry from the realtime database that i looked up through a query but i am getting unexpected results for both the ref and key properties.

```
ref('photos/users/USERID')
    .orderByChild('photoname')
    .equalTo('photoname i want to look up')
    .limitToFirst(1)
    .query('once')
    .then(snapshot => {
        // correct data at 'photos/users/USERID/PHOTOID'
        const entry = snapshot.val(); 

        // seems to be the ref to photos/users/USERID'
        const ref = snapshot.ref; 

        // seems to be USERID
        const key = snapshot.key
    })
```

Why aren't these the ref/key to the entry i just found? And what is the best approach to remove this entry?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you execute a query against the Firebase Database, there will potentially be multiple results. So the snapshot contains a list of those results. Even if there is only a single result, the snapshot will contain a list of one result.

Your code needs to take this list into account, and iterate over `snapshot.forEach()` to get the actual matching item:

```
ref('photos/users/USERID')
    .orderByChild('photoname')
    .equalTo('photoname i want to look up')
    .limitToFirst(1)
    .query('once')
    .then(snapshot => {
      snapshot.forEach(child => {
        const entry = child.val();     
        const ref = child.ref;     
        const key = child.key
      });
    })
```

Comment: Is there a way to access these children by some kind of index? So if i do a limit-by-1 query, can i grab the first (and only) result without having to iterate?

Comment: A list of one item is still a list, so you will need to iterate. If you want to prevent that, you can do `once('child_added'`. But that's sacrificing code clarity (and thus maintainability) more than I'd recommend.

Comment: i am currently doing this https://pastebin.com/5nhaauTa which is a bit ugly, so i was wondering if there is something like `getChildAt(0)` (although i should be able to improve that code by using `array.reduce`)

Answer (score 0):

Your ref and key are based on ref('photos/users/USERID'), not the filtered subset you have created.  Is there any reason you wouldn't call ref('photos/users/USERID/PHOTOID')?

Comment: i don't have the id of the photo yet, that was what i was trying to query and (after that) access by the ref/key property. But apparently i have to iterate over the results first.

Comment: Gotcha - I don't know if there is an alternative, but I approach this by calling it, getting the id, calling that, and deleting it