# How to return a single FirebaseObjectObservable from a FirebaseListObservable query

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm building a game using Angular 4 and Firebase Realtime DB.  I have a Firebase DB layout like this:

```
FB -> player_list-> -KyagqWEM-cqUoppGe_x
                        id:33061
                        name:Joe
                   -KyadrWSD-aqUeedBv_w
                        id:22037
                        name:Cara
```

In my app I'd like to create a FirebaseObjectObservable on a specific player, Joe in this example.  In my Ng Database Service I've created a method that looks like this:

```
getPlayerFromId(playerId: number): FirebaseListObservable<Player[]> {
  this.player = this.database.list(this.playerBasePath, {
    query: {
      orderByChild: 'id',
      equalTo: playerId,
      limitToFirst: 1
    }
  })
  return this.player;
}
```

A query seems to be the best way to find a specific node in my Firebase database, unfortunately queries seem to only return a list, even if that list is only one item in length.  In my component It's fairly easy to get the one player object, with code like this:

```
  getPlayer(playerId: number){
    this.studentService.getPlayerFromId(playerId)
    .subscribe(data => {
      this.player = data[0];
    })
  }
```

Is there a more elegant way to return one FirebaseObjectObservable from a list query?  I've tried map and filter, but apparently those are not supported by FirebaseListObservable.

Answer (score 0):

Because the returned result is a list you need to loop through to get the object

```
getPlayer(playerId: number){
this.studentService.getPlayerFromId(playerId)
.subscribe(data => {
  data.forEach(player => {
    this.player = player;
  })

 })
}
```

Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47273774/787187)

Answer (score 0):

```
    Try with forEach but as this.player will get its data asynchronously from firebase

this.player= this.af.database.list(this.playerBasePath);
        this.player.forEach(element => {
            console.log(element);
        });

    Above code you will be iterating before the data actually there. So for this
    you can add the option


     preserveSnapshot: true

        this.studentService.getPlayerFromId(playerId, { preserveSnapshot: true})
            .subscribe(snapshots=>{
                snapshots.forEach(snapshot => {
                  console.log(snapshot.key, snapshot.val());
                });
            })
```